# Add Contents Dynamically to java swing jpanel

Tags: java, swing, dynamic

I am new to java. I was Developing apps in c# in past. I am using NetBeans gui designer. I have created a new JFrame in which layout is set to group layout in which there's scrollpane. I am adding components on runtime by using following code.

```
MyScrollPane.add(new javax.swing.JButton("Button1");
MyScrollPane.add(new javax.swing.JCheckBox("CheckBox1");
this.revalidate();
```

The problem is that these components are not showing in scrollpane.
Another problem is that there is no option for absolute layout. Because I want to generate a scrollable list which will get values from database and generate list at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

NetBeans gui designer leverages `GroupLayout` to facilitate building of UIs. Adding components to this layout manager at runtime involves adding horizontal & vertical sequential groups which can be quite complex. A good reason to start coding using standard layout managers when starting starting out.

Comment: Thank you for you response. Yes you are right i changed the layout to null in coding and add buttons. But when I add components to any panel it works fine in constructor. But When I add it using Button click event it does not shows up.

Comment: null layout = no layout manager. Swing was designed to use layout managers, `BorderLayout`, `FlowLayout`...

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be adding anything to a JScrollPane (I assume MyScrollPane is a JScrollPane). Your buttons should be added the JPanel that is the view of the scroll pane.